# The shapes of general lemniscates (i.e., Cassinian curves) on the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, plane-curves

On the complex plane, curves given by an equation of the form:
$$ |z-z_1|\cdot |z-z_2| \cdots |z-z_n| = C  $$
with $ C \gt 0$, are known as general lemniscates, or Cassinian curves with $n$ foci.

I find it's difficult to depict their shapes on the complex plane. Can you tell me  their general shapes, or where can I find them?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mathcurve.com/courbes2d/cassinienne/cassinienne.shtml
(in French, but the figures are easy to find...)

Comment: This is a nice link, but at least a short (English?) summary of what's in the link would be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in a deep study of such curves have a look here:

http://www.mathe8.uni-bayreuth.de/Personen/CatPers/PubliCat/POlLemn-CatPal-Topology.pdf

you should also have a look to there referens therein.